# "Error executing command: No feature matching camel-sql-orders/0.0.0"

Tags: java, sql, apache-camel, apache-servicemix

When I run the command `features:install camel-sql-orders` in `ServiceMix` its giving error

> Error executing command: No feature matching camel-sql-orders/0.0.0

Please Help me how to resolve that

Answer (score 3):

There is no feature named `camel-sql-orders` in ServiceMix

```
karaf@root> features:list | grep sql
[uninstalled] [2.14.1          ] camel-josql                             camel-2.14.1
[uninstalled] [2.14.1          ] camel-sql                               camel-2.14.1
[uninstalled] [5.4.0           ] examples-camel-sql-derby                servicemix-examples-5.4.0
[uninstalled] [5.4.0           ] examples-camel-sql-pgsql                servicemix-examples-5.4.0
[uninstalled] [5.4.0           ] examples-camel-sql-h2                   servicemix-examples-5.4.0
```

You should install one of the `examples-camel-sql-*` features according to the database you want to use. These features contain the `camel-sql-orders` bundle

```
karaf@root> features:info examples-camel-sql-h2
Description of examples-camel-sql-h2 5.4.0 feature
----------------------------------------------------------------
Feature has no configuration
Feature has no configuration files
Feature depends on:
  camel-sql 2.14.1
Feature contains followed bundles:
 mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-dbcp/1.4_3
 mvn:org.osgi/org.osgi.compendium/5.0.0
 mvn:com.h2database/h2/1.3.170
 mvn:org.apache.servicemix.examples/camel-sql-datasource-h2/5.4.0
 mvn:org.apache.servicemix.examples/camel-sql-orders/5.4.0
Feature has no conditionals.
```

If you don't want to use any of these features you can create your own in simillar way like here https://github.com/apache/servicemix/blob/servicemix-5.4.x/assembly/src/main/filtered-resources/examples.xml#L59-L80

You can also install the bundle (and all necessary dependencies) manually

```
features:install camel-sql
osgi:install -s mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-dbcp/1.4_3
osgi:install -s mvn:org.osgi/org.osgi.compendium/5.0.0
osgi:install -s mvn:com.h2database/h2/1.3.170
osgi:install -s mvn:org.apache.servicemix.examples/camel-sql-datasource-h2/5.4.0
osgi:install -s mvn:org.apache.servicemix.examples/camel-sql-orders/5.4.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your response i tried to install third one examples-camel-sql-derby it giving error  **  Error executing command: Can't install feature examples-camel-sql-derby/0.0.0:

Can not resolve feature:
Unsatisfied requirement(s):
---------------------------
   package:(&(package=org.apache.camel.example.sql))
      Apache ServiceMix :: Examples :: Camel SQL :: Datasource Derby **

Comment: I have just installed it with following command `features:install -v examples-camel-sql-derby`

Comment: I am trying to do some sql database operation in camel servicemix its giving error    Unsatisfied  requirement(s):                                                                              package:(&(package=org.apache.camel.example.sql))
     Apache ServiceMix :: Examples :: Camel SQL :: Datasource Derby                                                                                                                  
  package:(&(package=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc))
     Apache ServiceMix :: Examples :: Camel SQL :: Orders

Comment: Hello KSobkowiak, I am doing Sql opeartion using JDBC Driver in camel it BUILD SUCCESSFULLY but when i run its giving  Error Unsatisfied requirement com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc

Comment: What did you do exactly? The ServiceMix features don't use sqlserver jdbc driver. Have you defined your own feature? Coudl you create a neq question where you describe what you want to do?